# multiply two fields in group by SAQL

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I have this below SAQL. What i want in end result is

> sum(q_A.'Revenue' * q_A.'Opportunity.Probability')/100) for each month

basically Revenue is OpportunityLineSchedule field and Probability is Opportunity field. I want for sum((Revenue * Probablity)/100) for each month

```
q = load "TestDataset";
q = filter q by 'Opportunity.Type' in ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
q = filter q by 'OpportunityLineItemId.Test__c' != "Transport";
q = filter q by date('ScheduleDate_Year', 'ScheduleDate_Month', 'ScheduleDate_Day') in ["current year".."current year"];
q_A = filter q by 'Opportunity.IsWon' == "true" && date('Opportunity.CloseDate_Year', 'Opportunity.CloseDate_Month', 'Opportunity.CloseDate_Day') in ["1 quarter ago".."current quarter"]; 
q_C = filter q by 'Opportunity.IsClosed' == "false";
r = load "Test2Dataset";
r = filter r by date('Quarter_Start_Date__c_Year', 'Quarter_Start_Date__c_Month', 'Quarter_Start_Date__c_Day') in ["current year".."current year"];
result = group q_A by ('ScheduleDate_Year', 'ScheduleDate_Month') full, q_C by ('ScheduleDate_Year', 'ScheduleDate_Month') full, r by ('Quarter_Start_Date__c_Year', 'Quarter_Start_Date__c_Month');
result = foreach result generate coalesce(q_A.'ScheduleDate_Year' + "~~~" + q_A.'ScheduleDate_Month', q_C.'ScheduleDate_Year' + "~~~" + q_C.'ScheduleDate_Month') as 'ScheduleDate_Year~~~ScheduleDate_Month', sum(q_A.'Revenue' ) as 'A', max(q_A.'Opportunity.Probability') as 'C';
result = order result by 'ScheduleDate_Year~~~ScheduleDate_Month';
result = limit result 2000;
```

Comment: one workaround you might consider is creating a formula field on the schedule object that does the multiplication for you. then summarize that in your saql. haven't tried it, there could be limitations around aggregating a formula field

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is aggregate each measure separately.  The following should work.

```
sum(q_A.'Revenue') * sum(q_A.'Opportunity.Probability') / 100 as 'new_measure'
```

If instead, you are not able to sum the probability metric you could use [average()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_fn_agg_avg.htm) as your aggregation function.  As long as the probability is the same for all rows in your group it should be fine.  [first()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_fn_agg_1st.htm) or [last()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_fn_agg_last.htm) are other functions to consider but just check the behavior before implementing it.